# Array Assignment in Functional Programming JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, functional-programming

When declaring a new local variable inside a function and assigning it to a global variable that is equal to an array, what is better?

Option 1: Using the Spread Operator:

```
let globalArray = [1, 2, 4];

function add (arr, value) {

  let newArray = [...arr];

  newArray.push(value);
  return newArray;
  
}

console.log(add(globalArray, "red"));
```

Option 2: NOT using the Spread Operator:

```
let globalArray = [1, 2, 4];

function add (arr, value) {

  let newArray = arr;

  newArray.push(value);
  return newArray;
  
}

console.log(add(globalArray, "red"));
```

I can't see the difference in the output. Should the Spread Operator be used or not?

Comment: The second one will mutate the global array, thus producing an observable effect. Therefore, it's impure. FP strives for purity in order to reign in side effects

Comment: Side note: `...` isn't, and can't be, an operator. Operators can't do what `...` does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value)

Comment: There is no "better". Your 2 code snippets are _functionally different_. One mutates the global variable, the other doesn't. What you use depends on what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "better" without criteria, although we can probably infer some criteria here. :-)

Using `push` without making a copy (your "NOT" option) **mutates** the original array passed to your function (the global one), which is usually not done in functional programming. FP tends to embrace using immutable data structures and pure functions (loosely: functions without side effects).

If you don't want to mutate the global array, use spread or `concat` or similar. For instance, with spread syntax (no need for `push` after, we can include `value` in the array literal):

```
let newArray = [...arr, value];
```

```js
let globalArray = [1, 2, 4];

function add (arr, value) {
    const newArray = [...arr, value];
    return newArray;
}

const updated = add(globalArray, "red");
console.log(updated);
console.log(updated === globalArray); // false
console.log(globalArray); // unchanged
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you want to mutate the global array, use `push` on the array passed in:

```js
let globalArray = [1, 2, 4];

function add (arr, value) {
    let newArray = arr;
    newArray.push(value);
    return newArray;
}

const updated = add(globalArray, "red");
console.log(updated);
console.log(updated === globalArray); // true!
console.log(globalArray); // changed!
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

...but again, that's not typically done in FP. As I understand it (I'm not deep into FP), even if you wanted to update `globalArray`, you'd usually do it by reassigning it: `globalArray = add(globalArray, "red")`.